# jQuery filter select options by text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select list where I want to filter the options from a text input.

I wrote this jQuery code:

```
$('#NotPublishedSelectFilter').keyup(function () {
    console.log("NotPublishedSelectFilter keyup");
    var filterText = $(this).val();
    console.log("filterText: " + filterText);
    var allOptions = $('#NotPublishedSelect').find('option');
    allOptions.each(function (i, e) {
        console.log(i);
        if (e.text().indexOf(filterText) != -1) {
            e.show();
            console.log("show");
        } else {
            e.hide();
            console.log("hide");
        }
    });
});
```

However I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: e.text is not a function`. I get into the each loop so there should be some option for e.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `$(e)` or `$(this)`

Comment: Thanks, i forgot about that.. working now.

Comment: `$('#NotPublishedSelect').find('option:contains(' + filterText + ')').show()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the current value in a jQuery object to have access to the `.text()` method. Try:

```
    $('#NotPublishedSelectFilter').keyup(function () {
        console.log("NotPublishedSelectFilter keyup");
        var filterText = $(this).val();
        console.log("filterText: " + filterText);
        var allOptions = $('#NotPublishedSelect').find('option');
        allOptions.each(function (i, e) {
            console.log(i);
            if ($(this).text().indexOf(filterText) != -1) {
                $(this).show();
                console.log("show");
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
                console.log("hide");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your selector within loop :-

```
$('#NotPublishedSelectFilter').keyup(function () {
    console.log("NotPublishedSelectFilter keyup");
    var filterText = $(this).val();
    console.log("filterText: " + filterText);
    var allOptions = $('#NotPublishedSelect').find('option');
    allOptions.each(function (i, e) {
        console.log(i);
        if ($(e).text().indexOf(filterText) != -1) {
            $(e).show();
            console.log("show");
        } else {
            $(e).hide();
            console.log("hide");
        }
    });
});
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need object variable, but accessing event variable. So please use this one

```
$('#NotPublishedSelectFilter').keyup(function () {
    console.log("NotPublishedSelectFilter keyup");
    var filterText = $(this).val();
    console.log("filterText: " + filterText);
    var allOptions = $('#NotPublishedSelect').find('option');
    allOptions.each(function (i, e) {
        console.log(i);
        $(this).text()
        if ($(this).text().indexOf(filterText) != -1) {
            $(this).show();
            console.log("show");
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
            console.log("hide");
        }
    });
});
```